# image not displaying when it is imported

Tags: html, css

I have a section where it has a background-image and one more image on the top. I added the source link of an image but I am display it on the front end. Down below is the code I tried

```
<section>
<div  class="BuyPartsEase_container">
         <div class="BuyPartsEase_wrapper">
                  <div class="BuyPartsEase_mobileImage">
                        <img src="https://petromin-dev.codilar.in/media/mobileview_1.png" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="BuyPartsEase_content">
                        <div class="BuyPartsEase_imageTitle">
                            <h1>BUY PARTS AT EASE.</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="BuyPartsEase_imageText">
                            <p>Experience the all new partsandservices.com<br/> from your mobile without installing<br/> any mobile app.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="BuyPartsEase_features">
                            <div class="BuyPartsEase_safeandsecure">
                                <div class="BuyPartsEase_featuresImage">
                                        <img src="{{media url=&quot;safe-and-secure.png&quot;}}" alt="" /> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="BuyPartsEase_featuresContent">
                                    <p class="BuyPartsEase_featureTitle">Safe & Secure</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="BuyPartsEase_fastandreliable">
                                <div class="BuyPartsEase_featuresImage">
                                    <img src="{{media url=&quot;fast-and-reliable.png&quot;}}" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="BuyPartsEase_featuresContent">
                                    <p class="BuyPartsEase_featureTitle">Fast & Reliable</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="BuyPartsEase_userfriendly">
                                <div class="BuyPartsEase_featuresImage">
                                      <img src="{{media url=&quot;user-friendly.png&quot;}}" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="BuyPartsEase_featuresContent">
                                    <p class="BuyPartsEase_featureTitle">User Friendly</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
</section>
```

The above is the `html` code and down below is the `CSS` I applied for that

```css
        .BuyPartsEase_container{
                background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.77), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.77)), url({{media url=&quot;Mask_Group_6_2x.jpg&quot;}});
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center center;
            width: 100vw;
            padding: 70px 50px;
                display: flex;
                position: relative;
            margin-left: -260px;
    }
    .BuyPartsEase_wrapper{
            display: flex;
            color: white;
            margin-left: 600px;
        }
    .BuyPartsEase_content{
            text-align: justify;
            margin-top: 115px;
            margin-left:230px;
        }
    .BuyPartsEase_imageText{
            line-height: 30px;
           font-size: 18px;
        }
    .BuyPartsEase_features{
            display: flex;
        }
    .BuyPartsEase_featureTitle{
            font-size: 15px;
        }
    .BuyPartsEase_safeandsecure,
    .BuyPartsEase_fastandreliable,
    .BuyPartsEase_userfriendly
    {
            margin: 15px;
        }
```

I am able to display the icon but I am not able to display the mobile image from the below `div`

```
<div class="BuyPartsEase_mobileImage">
     <img src="https://petromin-dev.codilar.in/media/mobileview_1.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: Working fine https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/qaxhfywg/

Comment: but its working perfectly fine when i tried it

Answer (score 0):

Try out to modify this line of code from your CSS file into this :

```
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.77), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.77)), url("media url=&quot;Mask_Group_6_2x.jpg&quot");
```

The only reason it was not showing before is due to the absence of quotation from your (url)